# Why curl_global_cleanup will clean ssl environment?

Tags: ssl, openssl, libcurl

The libcurl function curl_global_cleanup will call EVP_cleanup, it will clean all ssl environment, so other module of this program will can not use ssl, eg. md5 algorithm.So when can I use curl_global_cleanup?

Answer (score 1):

libcurl will init and cleanup all its doings and all its 3rd party libraries when you call its global init/cleanup functions. Because that's what they're documented to do and otherwise other users will complain on the memory leaks.

If you use OpenSSL yourself, you should independently init it so that you then also need to clean it up afterwards and OpenSSL should handle that just fine (which traditionally through time hasn't always been true).

Alternatively, (which is more of a sort of work-around than a proper "fix") you just make sure that you move the `curl_global_cleanup` call to happen well after your last use of OpenSSL.